# Is every subgroup of $S_n$ the Galois group of some extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Is every subgroup of $S_n$ the Galois group of some extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

It is well known that most (in some suitable sense) polynomials $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $d$ and coefficients $|a_i| \leq N$ have Galois group isomorphic to $S_d$. On a somewhat related note, is it known whether every subgroup of $S_n$ is isomorphic to the Galois group of some extension of $\mathbb{Q}$? I believe this was a conjecture of Noether, though I can't find anything about its progress.

Comment: Note  "every subgroup of $S_n$" is basically the same as "every finite group" if there is no restriction on $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as the inverse Galois problem, and as of today, it is still unknown.

Comment: It is known to be true for abelian groups and soluble groups (in particular $p$ groups)

Comment: In addition to abelian and soluble groups, it is also known for symmetric and alternating groups.